# Selenium find_elements_by_css_selector returns an empty list

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, css-selectors

I'm trying to select all the ids which contain `coupon-link` keyword with the following script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://udemycoupon.discountsglobal.com/coupon-category/free-2/")
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id~=\"coupon-link\"]')
print(elems)
```

But I got an empty list `[]` as the result. What's wrong with my css_selector?

I've tested that `find_elements_by_css_selector('[id=\"coupon-link-92654\"]')` works successfully. But I want to select all the coupon-links, not just one of them.

I referenced the document at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium CSS only support three partial match operators viz.- `$^*`.

CSS partial match expression is not correct- Use `*` or `^` details at [here](http://seleniumtestautomationtipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2013/01/find-elements-with-partial-match-on.html) and [here](http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors). You can use `xpath` too.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://udemycoupon.discountsglobal.com/coupon-category/free-2/")

#select by css
#try *
css_lnks = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*=coupon-link]')]
#or try ^
#css_lnks = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id^=coupon-link]')]

#select by xpath
xpth_lnks = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@id,'coupon-link-')]")]

print xpth_lnks
print css_lnks
```

Comment: Thank you :). I wish I can know how to use `~=` correctly. 

After reading the descriptions at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), I cannot tell the difference between `~=` and `*=`.

Answer (score 1):

The `~=` selector selects by value delimited by spaces. In that sense, it works similarly to a class selector matching the class attribute.

Since IDs don't usually have spaces in them (because an id attribute can only specify one ID at a time), it doesn't make sense to use `~=` with the id attribute.

If you just want to select an element by a prefix in its ID, use `^=`:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id^=\"coupon-link\"]')
```